# One trigger to activate two functions

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Self taught noob, working in google sheets, sorry in advance for the mess here. I am trying to pull data from two cells into a new sheet. Both of these are pulled in after I trigger them with an onEdit. I need to enter a value and hit enter on both cells for them to be placed into the new sheet. How would I set this up so that when I trigger "D9" I would pull in "C9" plus "D9"?

```
function onEdit(e){
// Set a comment on the edited cell to indicate when it was changed.
 if(e.range.getA1Notation() === 'C9'){
 var input = e.range.getValue();


 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var inputSheet = sheet.getSheetByName("input")
 var masterSheet = sheet.getSheetByName("master inventory");

 var currentRow = inputSheet.getRange("E9").getValue(); 

 masterSheet.getRange("A3:A1000").getCell(currentRow, 1).setValue(input);
 inputSheet.getRange("E9").setValue(currentRow, 1);
 }
if(e.range.getA1Notation() === 'D9'){
 var input = e.range.getValue();
 e.range.clearContent();

 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var inputSheet = sheet.getSheetByName("input")
 var masterSheet = sheet.getSheetByName("master inventory");

 var currentRow = inputSheet.getRange("E9").getValue(); 

 masterSheet.getRange("B3:B1000").getCell(currentRow, 1).setValue(input);
 inputSheet.getRange("E9").setValue(currentRow + 1);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var x=e.source.getSheetName()
  if( x == "input" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet 
    var y = e.range.getSheet().getActiveCell();
    var z= e.range.getSheet().getActiveCell().getA1Notation()
    var row=e.range.getSheet().getActiveCell().getRow()
    if(z=="D9" && x=="input"){
      var cell=e.range.getSheet().getActiveCell().getValue()
      e.range.getSheet().getActiveCell().clearContent()
       var nextCell =e.range.getSheet().getActiveCell().offset(0,-1).getValue()
        e.range.getSheet().getActiveCell().offset(0,-1).clearContent()
        var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
       var masterSheet = sheet.getSheetByName("master inventory");
      masterSheet.getRange("A3:A1000").getCell(row-2, 1).setValue(nextCell);
      masterSheet.getRange("B3:B1000").getCell(row-2, 1).setValue(cell);
    }}}
```